# FTP Client ul/dl in Universal Windows app

Tags: c#, sockets, ftp, uwp, universal

I'm struggling with uploading and downloading files to a FTP server in UWP/Windows Store apps.
The [FtpWebRequest Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) is missing so you have to use your own Ftp Client. I haven't found any working open-source libraries for this yet. I tried [Windows 8.1 Sockets: Ftp Client Sample with Sockets in C#/Xaml](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-8-SocketsFtp-4fc23b33); The directory listing works fine but the up/download breaks after a few bytes. Maybe a buffer issue? This is the upload stream, the download function is on the msdn site.

```
using (var stream = await ftpClient.OpenWriteAsync(newFilePath))
{
    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filecontent);
    await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
    await stream.FlushAsync();
}
```

or

```
using (var stream = await OpenWriteAsync(destination))
{
    // A more efficient way, maybe a DataReader can be used here
    using (var readStream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        var buffer = new byte[512].AsBuffer();
        var resultingBuffer = new byte[0];

        while (true)
        {
            IBuffer readBuffer = await readStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 512, InputStreamOptions.Partial);

            if (readBuffer.Length == 0) break;

            resultingBuffer = resultingBuffer.Concat(readBuffer.ToArray()).ToArray();
        }

        await stream.WriteAsync(resultingBuffer.AsBuffer());
        await stream.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

I read that the FTP upload is not supported by the `BackgroundTransfer` class. Has someone found a solution for loading files to a password-protected FTP server in UWP apps?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: So which of those two code snippets break? On what occasion does it break?

Comment: In both cases the file is created but the writing breaks at a filesize of 2kb. The download stream behaves in almost the same way. Very small files can be downloaded, but larger files >1mb get cropped. That's why I'm assuming that it's a buffer issue.

Comment: I managed to do this with a php file that I authenticated against. I uploaded the file to the PHP page and the PHP page saved it for me. Would that be a workaround for you?

Comment: I was thinking about your question a bit more and want to ask you, what this is for? What is the exact purpose of the FTP? Because a direct access to (S)FTP via UWP is not very secure.

Comment: My app generates files that the user loads from another program at a later time. These files should be easily accessible to the user from anywhere and on different devices. I thought that a ftp server would be a user-friendly and adequately secure solution. Currently, a separate ftp program (Filezilla) is used to upload the files. I wanted to simplify the data flow by adding a ftp upload modul to my app.

Comment: @user3079834 After hours of research and testing, I realised that your suggestion is probably the best workaround. Thanks a lot!